# Fullcalendar show textbox if date is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function, which prompts a box asking for my event name.

```
/* when user select timeslot this option code will execute.
   It has three arguments. Start, end, and allDay.
   Start means starting time of event.
   End means ending time of event.
   allDay means if events is for entire day or not.
*/
                        
select: function (start, end, allDay)
{
    /*
    after selection user will be prompted for enter title for event.
    */
                           
    var title = prompt("Titulo do Evento");
                            
    /*
    if title is entered calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar database.
    */
```

I want to change this, and instead show a hidden textbox on the page itself where I'll insert the event name.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself to achieve the desired result?

Comment: yes. I looked at some examples using a function to make style.display=='none'" or style.display=='block', but those work with document.getElementById, if a checkbox is selected or I click on something with an id etc... What i have here is different so I don't know how I can trigger a function like that